# Meaning of escaped unicode characters in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, unicode

In JSON, Unicode characters can be escaped using the `\uXXXX` notation.  I assume the `XXXX` obviously refers to a Unicode code point in hexadecimal.

But since there are only 4 digits, does this mean there is no way to escape codepoints which are `> 0xFFFF`?

Or does the `\uXXXX` not actually encode abstract *code points*, but actually units of UTF-16-BE encoded bytes?

Comment: JavaScript Unicode representation is sort-of broken.

Comment: [JavaScript has a Unicode problem.](http://mths.be/jsu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `\uXXXX` and yes, it is possible to represent characters greater than 0xFFFF using high and low surrogates along the lines you mention.

```
var s = '\uD87E\uDC04';
alert(s + '::' + s.length); // ::2
```

Comment: So you are saying that the `\uXXXX` notation is actually UTF-16 specifically

Comment: You might see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715980/javascript-strings-utf-16-vs-ucs-2 for the latter question. `charAt()`, for example, won't grab a whole abstract code point, so in that sense it may seem pre-UTF-16, but with surrogate support, JS can produce the necessary characters. How things are encoded internally (which may or may not be UTF16)--or in the document (which could be UTF-8, etc.)--are different matters from how the JS API works.