# How the JavaScript String is a set of "elements" of 16-bit unsigned integer values?

Tags: javascript, string

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting)

> JavaScript's String type is used to represent textual data. It is a set of "elements" of 16-bit unsigned integer values. Each element in the String occupies a position in the String. The first element is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on. The length of a String is the number of elements in it. You can create strings using string literals or string objects.

How the JavaScript String type is a set of "elements" of 16-bit unsigned integer values, why not 8-bit unsigned integer values?

Comment: Simply because you cant represent very many characters with just 8 bits. Think UNICODE and different character-sets.

Comment: Because unicode characters are 16-bit integers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8715980/476716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [full spec text](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) helps here:

> *The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more
>   16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of
>   2<sup>53</sup>-1 elements. The String type is generally used to represent textual
>   data in a running ECMAScript program, in which case **each element**
>   in the String **is treated as a UTF-16 code unit value**.*

Similar can be found in the [ES5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4).

Why not 8-bit unsigned integer values? That would have been equally possible, using UTF-8. But it wasn't done, and that's just how it is now.

Comment: Thanks, so that means that JavaScript string will require more memory than the string in the C language, right?

Comment: @jain: Yes, typically. Though there's nothing stopping engines from using a more memory-efficient representation, at the expense of more complicated indexed access. But notice that C doesn't really have strings, it has `char[]`, and you could do the same in JS with a `Uint8Array`. Also, C is obviously more limited at storing Unicode characters (though even JS is still limited, and needs to use surrogate pairs to represent code points outside of the BMP)

Answer (score 0):

Because EcmaScript is written using Unicode, a.k.a. UTF-16:

> ECMAScript source text is assumed to be a sequence of 16-bit code
>   units for the purposes of this specification.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-6