# String comparison - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my head around string comparisons in Javascript

```
function f(str){
  return str[0] < str[str.length -1]
}
f("a+"); // false
```

In ASCII: `'a' == 97, '+' == 43`

Am I correct in thinking my test: `f(str)` is based on ASCII values above?

Comment: you're close: it's the unicode value that matters when comparing two `String`s

Comment: `console.log( 'a' > '+' );  // true`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - A deeper understanding.

Comment: Check [this](https://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5) out (the relevant part begins with 'Else, both px and py are Strings').

Comment: @dan and actually that's exactly 97 and 43 :)

Comment: @nicael his point was that it works for characters beyond the ASCII set.

Comment: There's a related question, not quite a duplicate, that can shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715980/javascript-strings-utf-16-vs-ucs-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. It is based on unicode code units (not code points, this is the 16-bit encoded version), not ascii on values.

From the [ECMAScript 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value):

```
If both px and py are Strings, then
  If py is a prefix of px, return false. (A String value p is a prefix of String value q if q can be the result of concatenating p and some other String r. Note that any String is a prefix of itself, because r may be the empty String.)
  If px is a prefix of py, return true.
  Let k be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the code unit at index k within px is different from the code unit at index k within py. (There must be such a k, for neither String is a prefix of the other.)
  Let m be the integer that is the code unit value at index k within px.
  Let n be the integer that is the code unit value at index k within py.
  If m < n, return true. Otherwise, return false.
```

> **Note2**
>
> The comparison of Strings uses a simple lexicographic ordering on
>   sequences of code unit values. There is no attempt to use the more
>   complex, semantically oriented definitions of character or string
>   equality and collating order defined in the Unicode specification.
>   Therefore String values that are canonically equal according to the
>   Unicode standard could test as unequal. In effect this algorithm
>   assumes that both Strings are already in normalized form. Also, note
>   that for strings containing supplementary characters, lexicographic
>   ordering on sequences of UTF-16 code unit values differs from that on
>   sequences of code point values.

Basically it means that string comparison is based on a [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of "code units", which is the numeric value of unicode characters.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a function or a complicated test pulling a string apart for this. Just do `'a' < '+'` and learn from what happens. Or, more simply, check the char's charcode using `'a'.charCodeAt(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript engines are allowed to use either UCS-2 or UTF-16 (which is the same for most practical purposes).

So, technically, your function is based on UTF-16 values and you were comparing `0x0061` and `0x002B`.