# Buffer.byteLength returning drastically different byte length

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Using Node.js v5.1.0, I'm trying to determine the content length of a buffer. As such, I'm doing this:

```
Buffer.byteLength(self.data, 'utf8')
```

where `self.data` looks like this:

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 f0 00 f0 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 05 03 04 04 04 03 05 04 04 04 05 05 05 06 07 0c 08 07 07 07 07 0f 0b 0b 09 ... >
```

The image I'm loading is 109,055 bytes (111 KB on disk) on the file system (OS X), but my content length calculation is returning 198,147 bytes. If I set the encoding to `ascii`, it returns 104,793 bytes. Much closer, but still not correct.

Am I calculating this correctly? Do I need to do something to the buffer to get it to return the correct value? If I'm doing it right, why the discrepancy? If I'm doing it wrong, well, please share ;)

Comment: Don't you mean `self.data.byteLength`?

Comment: Ha! Yeah, that totally works. Thanks. Toss it in as an answer if you please? And if you know why the other way exists, works, but returns the wrong values, that would be super too ;)

Comment: [Buffer.byteLength](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) expects a string as the first argument, not a buffer, so maybe there is a conversion going on that messes with it. Is the data in `self.data` text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, [`Buffer.byteLength()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) returns the byte length of a string assuming a specific encoding.

The `Buffer` type is actually an `ArrayBuffer` which means it's length can be acquired via the [`byteLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/byteLength) property. Also, Node's implementation adds a `length` property that provides the same length.

Comment: > "The Buffer type is actually an ArrayBuffer"
WRONG! Citing from node.js docs for "Buffer": _"The Buffer class is a subclass of JavaScript's Uint8Array class and extends it with methods that cover additional use cases."_ -- https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer (node.js v20.5.0 at the time of this comment). To get the backing `ArrayBuffer` you have to use the `buffer` property on this Uint8Array-typed node.js "Buffer".

Answer (score 10):

I think the differences are as follows: (**EDIT**: As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233725/buffer-bytelength-returning-drastically-different-byte-length/53754898?noredirect=1#comment134696697_53754898), it appears some of the interpretations below are incorrect; awaiting corrected descriptions/summaries)

- [buffer.length](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buflength): Buffer's used+reserved length.
- [buffer.byteLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/byteLength): Buffer's used length.
- [buffer.toString().length](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftostringencoding-start-end): Number of characters in the default string rendering/interpretation of the buffer's bytes. You can change that rendering/intepretation by supplying a different encoding. (eg. `toString("ascii")`)
- [Buffer.byteLength(buffer, targetEncoding)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferbytelengthstring-encoding): Understanding the bytes in "buffer" to be using UTF-8 encoding (ie. the bytes are meant to be rendered/interpreted as a UTF-8 string), this returns the number of bytes needed to store that UTF-8 string in some specified encoding (`targetEncoding`).

On that last item (`Buffer.byteLength()`), I'm not completely sure my interpretation is correct, but that's the best I can figure from the brief description here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding

**EDIT**: As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233725/buffer-bytelength-returning-drastically-different-byte-length/53754898#comment108358475_53754898), the descriptions above appear to be incorrect for one of either `buffer.length` or `buffer.byteLength` (as they had a Buffer whose `byteLength` was higher than its `length`). If someone finds the explanation for the mismatch, please comment or edit this post with the fix!

Comment: I was trying to get the content length of a http response. When I use `buffer.length` and `buffer.toString().length,` I got the same value, `52700`. But when I try `buffer.byteLength`, I got `59241`. Also When I use `Buffer.byteLength(buffer, 'utf8')`, I got `89212`. `Content-Length` in the response header is `59241`. What's the difference between this methods and why they got different values? It confuses me. Could you help me?

Comment: @ZHANGLuyao It confuses me as well! I did my best attempt at defining the four methods from the info I could find online, but I may well have misunderstood some of them; particularly, the fact that `byteLength` is greater than `length` for your case, suggests that my definition for those two are incorrect (they'd suggest the opposite). :/ So unfortunately I'm in the same boat apparently. Though if you figure out the distinctions more accurately, feel free to make an edit suggestion!

Comment: 1. Understand [what Javascript strings are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341865/4510033). 2. The `toString` decodes the `Buffer`’s data in UTF-8 and encodes into _UTF-16_. 3. @user11081925 is messing with you with the misinformation. A `Buffer`’s `.byteLength` (inherited from `Uint8Array`) and `.length` are literally the same thing; what should be different than those two is `buffer.toString().length`, which counts in UTF-16.

Comment: I don’t get how this answer has got upvoted this much. Sorry if this sounds impolite, but this answer is just wrong.

Comment: @КонстантинВан Thanks for the corrections, and additional information. If you could summarize your corrections into new descriptions of the fields, I will update my answer with them.

Comment: @КонстантинВан I have changed it to a community-wiki answer so anyone can insert corrected descriptions/summaries now.

Answer (score 6):

The confusion in the OP is over the `Buffer.byteLength()` function, which takes a string and encoding as arguments, and is distinct from the `.byteLength` property on a buffer object.

The top voted answer also confuses these two concepts ([Buffer.byteLength returning drastically different byte length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233725/buffer-bytelength-returning-drastically-different-byte-length/53754898#53754898)), but I can no longer change my vote on it.

Here is an explanation:

```
let buf = Buffer.alloc(4); // <Buffer 00 00 00 00>
buf.length; // 4
buf.byteLength; // 4
buf.byteLength === buf.Length //true
```

At this point we know that `.byteLength` and `.length` as properties of a buffer object are strictly equal.

```
buf.write('ab'); // 2 - returns length of string 'ab' written to buf
buf.length // 4
buf.byteLength // 4
```

Both `.length`. and `.byteLength` return 4. There is no difference being made between the reserved length and used length, as the linked answer claims.

The accepted answer is correct about the `Buffer.byteLength(string, encoding='utf-8')` *function* (distinct from the `.byteLength` *property*), which gives the byte length of a string encoded with the specified encoding argument (default utf-8).

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my original question? I think this is better suited as a comment on the answer you've linked to.

Comment: @brandonscript - the confusion in the original question is that Buffer.byteLength() function returns the byte length of a string representation with a given encoding. Let me refactor to make clearer.

Unfortunately comments do not support multi-line code examples, so wrote this in answer format to be clearer to people coming afterwards (like myself) who are searching