# How to to convert string response to ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, python, django, pdf, pdfkit

From server I am getting the pdf response as string format, Now on client side, I want to convert it into ArrayBuffer, So that we can change again in pdf.

I am converting it into pdf, like following, **but is not pdf is getting corrupted.**

```
function str2ab(str) {
          var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
          var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
          for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          return buf;
    }
```

Above function I got from [stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers), I change Uint16Array to Uint8Array, pdfkit uses utf-8 uncode formate..

```
service.getAddress(reqData).then(function(response){
                if(response.data.error ===1){
                    toastr.error(response.data.message ,"Unsuccessful");
                }else{



                    var uintStr = str2ab(response.data);
                    var file = new Blob([uintStr], {
                        type : 'application/pdf'
                    });
                    //trick to download store a file having its URL
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    var a         = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href        = fileURL;
                    a.target      = '_blank';
                    a.download    = envelopeObj.customer_name+'_'+ 'envId_'+envelopeObj.envelope_id+'.pdf';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            });
```

To using pdf kit to convert it into string format.

```
add_str = render_to_string(address_template_path , {"address_dict": address_dict})
pdfkit.from_string(add_str, file_location)

address_pdf = open(file_location)
response = HttpResponse(address_pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')  # Generates the response as pdf response.
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename= %s' % envelope_id
```

Comment: Found a thread that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers

Comment: @ManojSureddi I tried this link, but it is not working..

Comment: "I change Uint16Array to Uint8Array", @geeks why exactly did you do that? do you understand the difference? How much do you know about file-encodings?

Comment: @Thomas I tried both, but not working, I change because pdfkit uses utf-8 encoding format ...

Comment: @geeks, well [JS uses UCS-2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8716329/6567275), and an ArrayBuffer is just a collection of bytes without meaning (on their own). From your code I'm not sure wich one you get in your response string, `utf-8`-encoded bytes or the correct "chars". And since I have no experience with Blobs and `a.download`, I don't know what output you need. The only thing I'm pretty sure is, that you somehow have to transcode this thing; not just push the last 8-Bit of the charCodes into an Uint8Array, leaving the other half of the ArrayBuffer empty